# OnPublish Event?

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

I want to trigger some code whenever I push out a new version of a Click-Once application that I'm building.  Maybe an event isn't the right word, but the idea is the same.

If any of you have suggestions, I'd appreciated it, thanks!

Comment: Do you want your code to trigger before the update is downloaded or after the update is downloaded?  Are you using automatic or programmatic updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to catch this on the client side, the server side, or in Visual Studio?